# When using mylyn trac connector how to attach screenshot?

Tags: eclipse, workflow, screenshot, trac, mylyn

I am using trac 0.10.3 but I am about to upgrade to the 0.11 version soon.

I have started using the mylyn connector in eclipse and I am finding it great, after watching the introduction here

[http://tasktop.com/videos/mylyn/webcast-mylyn-3.0.html (well worth the watch if you have a spare half an hour)](http://tasktop.com/videos/mylyn/webcast-mylyn-3.0.html)

From viewing this I see it is possible to attach a screen shot using mylyn to bug reports etc, my question is can I do this if I am using the trac connector ?

Am I missing something or is it only supported by some connectors? I can't find the option when I am connected to my trac install.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paul,

The screenshot attachment feature is supported by the Trac Connector when you use the rich task editor that communicates with your server over XML-RPC. The attachments feature won't be available if you are opening the task in the web browser or using the Web Templates connector.

Wesley Coelho 
[Tasktop Technologies](http://tasktop.com)

Comment: Thanks Wesley that's what I hoped for now I am using the trac conenctor that is not using the XML-RPC calls. Much appreciated answer. Upgrading over the next few days I can't wait to have the feature